# I keep running into an error message that says string index out of bounds. How to fix?

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

I keep running into an error, how to fix? What does it mean and why? I am very confused. Been repeatedly failing. How to avoid going beyond string length? I have no clue anymore.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 35
    at java.base/java.lang.StringLatin1.charAt(StringLatin1.java:47)
    at java.base/java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:693)
    at Mars.main(Mars.java:43)
```

Here's my code:

```
import java.lang.Math;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

public class Mars {
    /* decides whether a martian message contains a swear or not */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
      Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
      String m;
      String u;
      System.out.println("Please enter Martian username.");
      u = scan.nextLine();
      System.out.println("Please enter Martian message.");
      m = scan.nextLine();
      /* asks for message and username */
      System.out.println(u + " - " + m);
      /* prints the message */
      String f = (u + " - " + m);
      String um = f.toLowerCase();
      int L = um.length();
      /* loop variable */
      int V = 0;
      int qey = 0;
      int s$s = 0;
      /* swear variables */
      for (int c = 0; c <= L;){
          System.out.println(um.charAt(c));
          if (c > (L - 2)){
              
          }
          else if (um.charAt(c) == ' ' & um.charAt((c + 1)) == '^' & um.charAt((c + 2)) == '^' & um.charAt((c + 3)) == ' ' || c == 0 && um.charAt(c) == '^' & um.charAt((c + 1)) == '^' & um.charAt((c + 2)) == ' ' || c == (L - 2) & um.charAt(c) == ' ' & um.charAt(c + 1) == '^' & um.charAt((c + 2)) == '^'){
              V ++;
          }
          if (c > (L - 1)){
              
          }
          else if (um.charAt(c) == ' ' & um.charAt((c + 1)) == '$' & um.charAt((c + 2)) == ' ' || c == 0 & um.charAt(c) == '$' & um.charAt((c + 1)) == ' ' || c == (L - 1) & um.charAt(c) == ' ' & um.charAt(c + 1) == '$'){
              s$s ++;
          }
          if (c > (L - 3)){
              
          }
          else if (um.charAt(c) == ' ' & um.charAt((c + 1)) == 'q' & um.charAt((c + 2)) == 'e' & um.charAt((c + 3)) == 'y' & um.charAt((c + 4)) == ' ' || c == 0 && um.charAt(c) == 'q' & um.charAt((c + 1)) == 'e' & um.charAt((c + 2)) == 'y' & um.charAt((c + 3)) == ' ' || c == (L - 4) & um.charAt(c) == ' ' & um.charAt(c + 1) == 'q' & um.charAt((c + 2)) == 'e' & um.charAt(c + 3) == 'y'){
              qey ++;
          }
          c++;
      }
      /* checks if there are any swears and adds 1 to the variable assigned to that swear */
      System.out.println("Results:");
      if (qey >= 1 || s$s >= 1 || V >= 1){
          System.out.println("BAD" + "\n" + u + "\n" + "^^: " + V + "\n" + "qey: " + qey + "\n" + "$: " + s$s);
      }
      else{
          System.out.println("CLEAN");
      }
      /* checks for any swears */
    }
}
```

Comment: If you could post your code snippet, it would be helpful to reply correctly.

Comment: Just did it now. website being annoying with that stupid word to code ratio thing.

Comment: @IanLebowitz next time, try to use block code (indented 4 spaces) instead of inline code.

Comment: L is equal to the length of um. Your loop condition is ``int c = 0; c <= L;``. When it gets to L, c is out of bounds for um. Also, why do you do c++ at the end of the loop rather than in the for-loop?

Comment: I add it at the end because it will ignore the first letter if it adds on at the start.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Fixed it by adding some spaces to the end and making it so the for loop didn't go all the way.

```
      String f = (u + " - " + m + "                          ");
      String um = f.toLowerCase();
      int L = um.length();
      /* loop variable */
      int V = 0;
      int qey = 0;
      int s$s = 0;
      /* swear variables */
      for (int c = 0; c <= (L - 5);){
         if (um.charAt(c) == ' ' & um.charAt((c + 1)) == '$' & um.charAt((c + 2)) == ' ' || c == 0 & um.charAt(c) == '$' & um.charAt((c + 1)) == ' '){
              s$s ++;
         }
         if (um.charAt(c) == ' ' & um.charAt((c + 1)) == '^' & um.charAt((c + 2)) == '^' & um.charAt((c + 3)) == ' ' || c == 0 && um.charAt(c) == '^' & um.charAt((c + 1)) == '^' & um.charAt((c + 2)) == ' '){
              V ++;
         }
         else if (um.charAt(c) == ' ' & um.charAt((c + 1)) == 'q' & um.charAt((c + 2)) == 'e' & um.charAt((c + 3)) == 'y' & um.charAt((c + 4)) == ' ' || c == 0 && um.charAt(c) == 'q' & um.charAt((c + 1)) == 'e' & um.charAt((c + 2)) == 'y' & um.charAt((c + 3)) == ' '){
              qey ++;
         }
         c++;
      }
```

Comment: That is a rather odd definition of fixed.

Comment: That may be -- but it probably won't work for your instructor.

Answer (score 0):

If a String has length N, its characters are numbered 0, 1, ... N-1.

There is no charAt(N).  That index is off the end of the String.

Therefore, any loop has to run from 0 to N-1, not 0 to N.

That is,  `for (c = 0; c < N; c++)` and not `for (c = 0; c <= N; c++)`

---

This is one obvious case:

```
  for (int c = 0; c <= L;){
      System.out.println(um.charAt(c)
```

---

This is more subtle.

```
      if (c > (L - 2)){
          
      }
      else if (um.charAt(c) == ' ' & um.charAt((c + 1)) == '^' & um.charAt((c + 2)) == '^' ....
```

So, the maximum value of 'c' in the 'else' clause is c == L-2.  And therefore c+2 is L, which is off the end.

There are others like that.

Comment: What "didn't work"?  It is incontrovertible fact that the characters have indexes 0 to N-1. So, your job is to discover where your code is using an index >= N.  Eyeballing the code, I see at least 4 places where that will happen.